# How can I pluck out filter results?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-filter

I want to be able to pull out the ***best*** value from a filtered list of results, this is my test page:

http://plnkr.co/edit/MCLTKUGpIyuYYjv7DLFM?p=preview

Template

```
<div ng-controller="repeatController">
  <input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter results..." />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.names[0]}}
    </li>
    <li ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('repeatController', function($scope) {
  $scope.friends = [
    {names:['David King', 'Davey', 'oodavid', 'Queenie']},
    {names:['Paul King', 'Pablo', 'The Iron Paul']},
    {names:['Michael P O\'Keefe', 'Miguel Vennie']},
    {names:['James Griffiths', 'The Kraken', 'Thee Krakken']},
    {names:['Queen Elizabeth', 'The Queen']}
  ];
});
```

When I type "the" into the search box I see that these people have "the" in one of their names (which is the correct list)...

- Paul King
- James Griffiths
- Queen Elizabeth

...however, I want to pluck out the best match from the names array instead of just using the ***first*** value, so it should render like this:

- The Iron Paul
- The Kraken
- The Queen

Any pointers?

Comment: Would need a ranking algorithm. Look for a configurable search library to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I understood that you want to display only first value while displaying but while searching you want to display the subsets instead of first value. It can be achieved by following changes:

```
<ul>
    <!-- Filter the subset containing search text -->
    <span ng-repeat="friend in friends| filter:q as results">
      <!-- Filter again in subset to obtain the actual value -->
      <li ng-if="(!q && $first) || (q)" ng-repeat="name in friend.names| filter:q as results">
        <span>{{name}}</span>
      </li>
    </span>
    <span ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </span>
</ul>
```

Make use of condition `(!q && $first) || (q)` to display first value when there is no search text and display all when there is search text.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5hKhSOTCxUwoLNGwJHs?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Pruthvi - Plunker's down at the moment, I'll have a fiddle shortly. Looks good though!

Comment: I see, there's an issue of duplication though, so "the" gives me: The Iron Paul, The Kraken, Thee Krakken, The Queen. So The Kraken appears twice. I'll try creating a filter to pluck values :)